# PySpark: Muliple Where condition vs AND (&&)

Tags: pyspark, databricks

```
.where((col('Country')==Country) & (col('Year')>startYear))
```

I can do the where conditions both ways. I think the one below add readability. Is there any other difference and which is the best?

```
.where(col('Country')==Country)
.where(col('Year')>startYear)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [`explain`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.explain.html) is useful in order to understand how a query is performed. It shows the execution plan with all the steps involved and it can be used in this case to compare the two filtering strategies.

Give the following example:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = spark.createDataFrame([("Spain", 2020), 
                            ("Italy", 2020), 
                            ("Andorra", 2021), 
                            ("Spain", 2021), 
                            ("Spain", 2022)], ("Country", "Year"))
df.show()

Country = "Spain"
startYear = 2020
```

The extended output of the AND strategy is:

```
df.where((col('Country') == Country) & (col('Year') > startYear)).explain(True)

== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Filter (('Country = Spain) AND ('Year > 2020))
+- LogicalRDD [Country#80, Year#81L], false

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
Country: string, Year: bigint
Filter ((Country#80 = Spain) AND (Year#81L > cast(2020 as bigint)))
+- LogicalRDD [Country#80, Year#81L], false

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Filter (((isnotnull(Country#80) AND isnotnull(Year#81L)) AND (Country#80 = Spain)) AND (Year#81L > 2020))
+- LogicalRDD [Country#80, Year#81L], false

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Filter (((isnotnull(Country#80) AND isnotnull(Year#81L)) AND (Country#80 = Spain)) AND (Year#81L > 2020))
+- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[Country#80,Year#81L]
```

while the plan of the multiple where strategy is:

```
df.where(col('Country') == Country).where(col('Year') > startYear).explain(True)

== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Filter ('Year > 2020)
+- Filter (Country#80 = Spain)
   +- LogicalRDD [Country#80, Year#81L], false

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
Country: string, Year: bigint
Filter (Year#81L > cast(2020 as bigint))
+- Filter (Country#80 = Spain)
   +- LogicalRDD [Country#80, Year#81L], false

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Filter (((isnotnull(Country#80) AND isnotnull(Year#81L)) AND (Country#80 = Spain)) AND (Year#81L > 2020))
+- LogicalRDD [Country#80, Year#81L], false

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Filter (((isnotnull(Country#80) AND isnotnull(Year#81L)) AND (Country#80 = Spain)) AND (Year#81L > 2020))
+- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[Country#80,Year#81L]
```

The query engine came up with the same physical plan regardless the filtering strategy, thus the queries are equivalent. I agree with you the second one is better for readability

Answer (score 2):

if the question is readability, i would suggest something like this :
`.where(F.expr("Country <=> 'Country' and Year > 'startYear'")`

Here `<=>` is used for equality null safe, there is a something in spark where nulls values are ignored in condition.

I had worked with a sample , both are giving same results. So there would be no other differences.

```
data.show()
+---+---------+----+
| id|  Country|year|
+---+---------+----+
|  1|    india|2018|
|  2|      usa|2018|
|  3|   france|2019|
|  4|    china|2019|
|  5|    india|2020|
|  6|australia|2021|
|  7|    india|2016|
|  8|      usa|2019|
+---+---------+----+

data.where((col('Country')=='india') & (col('Year')>2017)).show() 


 #consider country:'india',startyear:2017
   +---+-------+----+
   | id|Country|year|
   +---+-------+----+
   |  1|  india|2018|
   |  5|  india|2020|
   +---+-------+----+


   data.where(col('Country')=='india')\
   .where(col('Year')>2017).show()

+---+-------+----+
| id|Country|year|
+---+-------+----+
|  1|  india|2018|
|  5|  india|2020|
+---+-------+----+
```

Comment: Question does not ask about readability

Comment: sorry, i got it. There is no other difference , both are same and if you ask me best i would recommend .where((col('Country')==Country) & (col('Year')>startYear))

Comment: I am not here to get up votes or something else. just sharing my knowledge, thats it.

Comment: You don't need `F.expr` inside the `where`, your suggestion works as `df.where(f"Country <=> '{Country}' and Year > '{startYear}'")`

Comment: yes i agree with you. `F.expr`  is standard way to keep null safe equality in both `equal_to` and `not_equal_to` condition. Let me know, i would share a sample code regarding the difference between two.